# ValueError + repetition I can't figure out

Tags: python, valueerror

I am new to programming. I have to write a script for a calculator.
I have two issues with it:

1. My 3rd prompt to enter a number repeats itself, and I am not sure why.
2. I get a `ValueError` instead of the calculation but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
def input_number1():
    prompt = 'Enter a number\n'
    num1 = int(input(prompt))
    if num1 <= 0:
        print('Error')
        input_number1()
    else:
        return num1


input_number1()


def input_operator():
    prompt = 'Enter [1] to add, [2] to substract, [3] to multiply or [4] to divide?\n'
    operator = int(input(prompt))
    if operator < 1 or operator > 4 :
        print('error')
        input_operator()
    else:
        return operator


input_operator()


def input_number2():
    prompt = 'Enter a number\n'
    num2 = int(input(prompt))
    if num2 <= 0 :
        print('Error')
        input_number2()
    else:
        return num2


input_number2()


num1 = input_number1()
operator = input_operator()
num2 = input_number2()


def do_calc():
    if operator == 1:
        print(num1 + num2)
    elif operator == 2:
        print(num1 - num2)
    elif operator == 3:
        print(num1 * num2)
    else:
        print(num1 / num2)


do_calc()
```

Can someone points me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error here is that you are calling `input_number1()`, `input_operator()` and `input_number2()` after the function definition so they call once after the function is defined and their return value is ignored, then once again to actually store and calculate the result.

And about the `ValueError` I can't seem to find where that might be, for me the code works fine after fixing the main problem. On what line does the problem happen?

Comment: I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/calculator.py", line 44, in <module>
    input_number1()
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/calculator.py", line 3, in input_number1
    num1 = int(input(prompt))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''  
  
I took off my function calls, and the error disappeared as well! Thank you so much!

Comment: Well that's just because you entered an invalid number. If it tries to parse `"hello"` as an int it will throw a `ValueError`.

Comment: Once I took off my function calls, everything worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I talked too fast :(  
The whole thing works if I enter the right numbers in, but if i don't, it creates error messages.

Comment: @ChrisVieulles try to handle the ValueError with try & except, this should make your script more robust.